# CSS3PIE file won't load

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I'm experiencing something very weird. I use PIE to have rounded corners in IE8. Everything was working fine at my current working directory. Then I made update to [github](https://github.com/LuckyLam34/HTML-Ass.git) and clone back to test if it's still working fine. And bum! PIE file won't load anymore. 
I don't know what is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Share the code that load the Pie library.

Comment: style.css: behavior: url(PIE.htc); PIE is at the same folder with index.html file